# AWS pandas etl job that is too big for lambda and too small for Spark - what to use?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I need to run a daily etl job that has to download some CSV files and run some pandas processing. The file is just big enough to where the lambda fails during processing, but spark seems overkill. Glue does not allow for pandas. What makes sense for daily processing?  I am currently considering the following options

- Do some workaround with chunksize for pandas read_csv
- Run as spark job even though data is not very big, just too big for lambda
- Try to run as Sagemaker processing job
- Run as script on EC2 instance

Ec2 will definitely work, but it feels like this should be handled by some dedicated AWS service. But which is the right (AWS) tool for the job?

Answer (score 1):

SageMaker Training and SageMaker Processing are definitely relevant services for small-to-large scale data processing, including arbitrary pandas execution. I have a slight preference for SageMaker Training. Despite its name, nothing forces you to do ML training in SageMaker Training! It has the following benefits:

1. It can use Spot
2. It is well integrated to the rest of AWS (good
   console experience, custom metrics + logs in Cloudwatch)
3. You can even try creatively using bayesian tuning to tune job execution time or costs!

In your situation I'd recommend to use the open-source SageMaker [Sklearn training container](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/frameworks/sklearn/using_sklearn.html), which has the benefit of having pandas installed, a high-level SDK and can be tested locally.

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense - esp since we're using Sagemaker for our production models...I just liked the visibility of lambdas controlled by a stepfunction before it the data is sent off to batch processing. Never considered using sagemaker training as preprocessing.  If I use sagemaker processing for pre and post processing, can I package them up into a Sagemaker inference pipeline? So I'd have pre-process, batch transform, post-process, all rolled up into a single sagemaker pipeline that is triggered? Are there memory or timeout restrictions, or is it fully scalable? Thanks!!

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/08/aws-step-functions-adds-support-for-amazon-sagemaker-processing/ - looks like I can just swap out lambdas for Sagemaker processing jobs and run through stepfunctions the same way

Comment: @LXandor yes Step Functions is a good idea. Inference Pipeline can also be used but it requires each container to respect the SageMaker invocation design so may be less flexible than custom code in Processing/Training jobs. Typically, I believe you will be constrained on the payload size communicated from container to container. It is appropriate for real-time inference on single requests, or with use in a Batch Transform task (which handles splitting a file into many small payloads)

Answer (score 0):

In scenarios like this you can use AWS [Glue python shell](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/01/introducing-python-shell-jobs-in-aws-glue/) jobs.You can now use Python scripts in AWS Glue to run small to medium-sized generic tasks that are often part of an ETL (extract, transform, and load) workflow.

Refer to this [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/add-job-python.html) to know more about how you can add a python shell job with pandas.